# Copy all but last two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a snippet in my code that works great but selects all the columns in each row. I need columns A-M but for the life of me cannot get what seems like a really simple adjustment to work properly.

Below is my code:

```
For i = 2 To ws1.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 12) = Sheets("main").Range("B4") Then ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code and see if it works:

```
For i = 2 To ws1.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 12) = Sheets("main").Range("B4") Then ws1.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Copy ws2.Cells(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
```

Comment: I appreciate the try, but that did the same thing - it copied the whole row. I actually tried something like that earlier but couldn't get it to work.